# Connecting SSH with OpenSSH key

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a CentOS 6 server and I want to connect to it with a private key.

On Windows, I use PuTTY Keygen and paste the public key in my server, in `.ssh/authorized_keys2` (also tried `authorized_keys`, don't remember why I'm using `authorized_keys2`).

Then, I save the private key "name.ppk" and use it with PuTTY (and pageant). Everything is ok until there. The connection is successful.

The problem comes when I try to connect from another Linux system.

I use the puttykeygen export option to export an OpenSSH key and use it from my other Linux system, but it doesn't work. It always says

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic)

Also tried to create the key from the other Linux systems with:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

(and `-t rsa`) and pasted the public key on my CentOS server, where I want to connect. I've tried to paste it in both files (`authorized_keys` and `authorized_keys2`) but nothing works.

In fact, I've tried to connect from another real CentOS server, one CentOS virtual server on the same Windows 7 that can connect using PuTTY and one Debian virtual server on that same Windows 7.

The CentOS virtual server and Debian virtual server can connect to each other using keys.

Also, the config is different. Both virtual servers have the `sshd_config` as default, while the main CentOS 6 server has a config I've found years ago trying to do it safer, disabling the login without key, etc.

Here is my CentOS 6 config (without some comments):

```
Port xxxx
Protocol 2

SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

UsePAM no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES 
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT 
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
X11Forwarding yes
UseDNS no

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: What permissions do the files have? Run `ls -la` in the .ssh directory to check. See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664723/ssh-key-authentification-with-users-in-group/14665284 for the correct permissions.

Comment: -rw-r--r--

If the permissions were wrong, do they work with putty? because I can connect with putty on windows, but can't with ssh on centos or debian

Comment: It's true that the client shouldn't matter with the permissions. Try connecting with `ssh -v host` to get debug output. You can give v parameter multiple times to be even more verbose. /var/log/auth.log may also help in deducing whatis wrong.

Comment: I finally got it. The problem was that I use a name for each private key (as in windows) but ssh always tries to use only id_dsa key

Comment: Good that you found the problem. You can specify the key to be used with option `-i`.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I will remember next time.